# Which simplified form of $-2\sqrt[3]{-250}$ is correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I simplified the cube root expression into two:

$10\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $-10\sqrt[3]{-2}$. Both yield the same approximation when I solved them using calculator. Which is correct? Or both should be answered if the question is simplifying?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sqrt[3]{-x}=-\sqrt[3]{x}$ for any real number $x$, so the two expressions are equal. The one without the minus signs ($10\sqrt[3]{2}$) looks simpler though, so I would use that for the simplified form.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct indeed, but $-10\sqrt[3]{-2}$ has two more $-$ signs than $10\sqrt[3]{2}$ and therefore this last expression is simpler.